# How do I map attachments submitted via mailhandler?

Tags: feeds, emails

In Drupal-7 I'm reading an imap mailbox with [mailhandler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31745/set-up-mailhandler-with-imap-gmail). I have the mapping setup via feeds. This processes text messages creating a node but messages with attachments don't have the attachments stored.

How do I store the attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file field and mapped the attachment.

1. Create the file field under structure/types. Set number of values to 'unlimited'.
2. Under the feeds mapping map attachments to File:URI